# Expand layout_weight with animation from 0.3 to 0.8

Tags: java, android, animation

I have fragment who slide up to 0.3 of height of screen...
now i want to animate it from 0.3 to 0.8 on button. But how do it? Can I animate a layout_weight? I need show more information after click on buton that why to rise height. objectAnimator didnt work.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:gravity="bottom">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_details"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
                    android:paddingTop="32dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_weight=".1"
                            android:src="@drawable/time" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".9"
                            android:text="TextView"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a `ValueAnimator` to animate a `float` from 0.3 to 0.8, and then use an `AnimatorUpdateListener` to update the `weight` value in your details view's `LayoutParams`.

```
LinearLayout details = findViewById(R.id.details);

ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.3f, 0.8f);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) details.getLayoutParams();
        params.weight = value;
        details.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
```

Now you can call `animator.start()` whenever you want to animate the view from 30% height to 80% height.